# How do I use regular expressions while mapping data from one array of objects to another?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have the below data

```
const data=[{"ID": 21,"Name": "Container 1","Type": "Oil", "Flowrate (bbl/min)": "","Density (g/cm3)":5.32,"Boiling point(F)": 135,"Melting Point (C)": 24},{"ID": "2","Name": "Container 2","Type": "Water", "Flowrate (bbl/min)": "","Density (g/cm3)": 9.18,"Boiling point(F)": 100,"Melting Point (C)": 22}]
```

Now I need to convert this in such a way that the unit system beside each of these property names should be removed

```
{"ID": 21,"Name": "Container 1","Type": "Oil", "Flowrate": "","Density": 5.32,"Boiling point": 135, "Melting Point": 24},{"ID": "12.25","Name": "Container 2","Type": "Water", "Flowrate": "","Density": 9.18,"Boiling point": 100,"Melting Point": 22,"Gel": ""}
```

I have tried using the conventional .map to do so but it is throwing error.

```
const result = data.map(({ ID, Name, Type, Flowrate (bbl/min),Density (g/cm3),Boiling point(F),Melting Point (C)}) =>({ ID: ID, Name: Name, Type: Type, Flowrate: Flowrate (bbl/min), Density: Density (g/cm3), Boiling Point :Boiling point(F),Melting Point: Melting Point (C)}))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const data=[{"ID": 21,"Name": "Container 1","Type": "Oil", "Flowrate (bbl/min)": "","Density (g/cm3)":5.32,"Boiling point(F)": 135,"Melting Point (C)": 24},{"ID": "2","Name": "Container 2","Type": "Water", "Flowrate (bbl/min)": "","Density (g/cm3)": 9.18,"Boiling point(F)": 100,"Melting Point (C)": 22}];

let d = data.map(obj=>{
   let o={};
   Object.keys(obj).forEach((key)=>{
    if(key.indexOf('(')>0){
      let prop = key.split('(')[0].trim();
      o[prop] = obj[key];
    }
    else{
     o[key] = obj[key];
    }
   });
   return o;
});
console.log(d);
```

Try this. There are mapper also like lodash which you can use.